# How to get more accurante results with Maps api with less characters

Tags: android, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

when requesting to this url:

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Mad&sensor=false&language=EN

Which (I try) means: Give me the points which addresses "contains" Mad, It returns me with some locations that have nothing to do with what I'm searching.

The goal is to build an addres autocomplete on Android.

This example i'm giving you is when I'm searching for Madrid, Spain... If I do a request to:

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Madrid&sensor=false&language=EN

I get what I expected, but why is it returning me some place on Hungary with the keyword "Mad".

Is there any way to get more accurate results when there are less characters?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want more accurate results whilst providing less information, I think the best option you have is to [add auto-complete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#add_autocomplete) entries manually, though this might be unreasonable if there are too many keywords you want to account for.

Alternatively, you can restrict your auto-complete to get results only from what can be seen in the viewport:

```
autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
```

Or restrict results to a specific country:

```
var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
var options = {
  types: ['(cities)'],
  componentRestrictions: {country: 'fr'}
};

autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
```